# Odoo testing for no-model

Tags: testing, odoo

I want to do some unit tests for my new Odoo module. In this module, I have some classes defined to do some tasks, like generating an xml from an invoice.
This class created does not inherit from `odoo.models.Model`, so it is not an Odoo model, it is just a script with a class to test.

So I think that I have two ways:

- **Using odoo.tests:**

```py
from odoo.addons.module_name.models.xml_invoice import XmlInvoice
from odoo.tests.common import TransactionCase, tagged


@tagged('post_install', '-at_install')
class TestXmlInvoice(TransactionCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestXmlInvoice, self).setUp()
        self.xml_invoice = XmlInvoice()

    def test_xml_invoice(self):
        res = self.xml_invoice.generate_xmlinvoice('test')
        self.assertEqual(res, True)
```

What returns:

```
RuntimeError: object unbound
```

In this way, if I bound the object with `XmlInvoice(self)`, I get this:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

- **Using unittest:**

```py
from module_name.models.xml_invoice import XmlInvoice
import unittest


class TestXmlInvoice(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestXmlInvoice, self).setUp()
        self.xml_invoice = XmlInvoice()

    def test_xml_invoice(self):
        res = self.xml_invoice.generate_xmlinvoice('test')
        self.assertEqual(res, True)
```

What returns this error:

```
    "Invalid import of %s.%s, it should start with 'odoo.addons'." % (self.__module__, name)
AssertionError: Invalid import of module_name.models.xml_invoice.XmlInvoice, it should start with 'odoo.addons'.
```

So, How can I test a class in Odoo that is not a model?